# How to remove cmake

Tags: command-line, macos

I recently installed `cmake` with the `./bootstrap` executable which is part of the source distribution. Now I don't need it and want to get rid of it. However, instead of downloading cmake as a dmg and dragging it into applications, as I normally would, I built it using the command line and now I am stuck with a tool on terminal I don't want. Any help on how to get rid of it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

`cd` into the directory with cmake's source code (the directory you ran `./bootstrap` in) then run:

```
make uninstall
```